# can't receive data from post call in my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, http-post

I have a html editor and I am trying to send the data via post call. I can see the data in javascript and it hits SendEmail method but in my controller request is empty. Why can't see the data in my controller?

```
 function SelectedReceipientsViewModel() {
 var self = this;
 self.packageDataForEmail = function () {   
    var request= tinymce.get("mailTextArea").getContent();
    return request;
};



self.submit = function () {
    var request = self.packageDataForEmail();
    $.post("SendEmail",request, function () {         
    }).done(function () {                  
    }).fail(function () {          
    });       
};
}
```

my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SendEmail(string request)
{
    string message = request;
    ......
    ...
}
```

Comment: This looks like you are not passing a valid URL to post. Assuming you are using Asp.Net MVC

Answer (score 1):

I created DtoEblast and add my property inside. for some reason string did not work. anyways this is working code.

```
self.packageDataForEmail = function () {       
    var Request = function (tinymceText) {
        this.TinymceText = tinymceText;
    };      
    var tinymceText = tinymce.get("mailTextArea").getContent();
    var request = new Request(tinymceText);
    return request;
};


 [HttpPost]
    public void SendEmail(DtoEblast request)
    {
      string message = request.TinymceText;
```

and it was giving 500 error without this line

```
<script>tinymce.init({forced_root_block : "",selector:'textarea'});</script>
```